# passing parameters to rewrited urls

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My project have data about different websites so I have rewritten urls using .htaccess so that when ever someone passes a name containing a dot(.) to my website, it shows the site.php page. here is my code for that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+(\.)[a-zA-Z0-9\_\.\-]+)/?$ site.php?url=$1
RewriteRule contact$ contact.php
```

This sends site name as parameter to site.php. Now I want one more parameter to be passed to is like it could have been passed in general, for ex. I want the site to get real time updated data, i want to pass `?update=true` so that it updates the data from internet rather then taking it from database. But passing parameter like this

```
http://www.mysite.com/anysite.com?update=true
```

isn't working, how can I pass additional parameters to my existing rewritten url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[QSA]` flag ("*query string append*") will append any received query string onto the rewritten URL.  I have also added the `[L]` flag as a best practice to prevent a match to your first rule also matching an additional rule later on in your chain, should one ever be added.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+(\.)[a-zA-Z0-9\_\.\-]+)/?$ site.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule contact$ contact.php [QSA,L]
```

However, if I have misunderstood the problem and you don't need for the browser to be sending `update=true` but rather just want to force it on all requests, simply add it to the rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+(\.)[a-zA-Z0-9\_\.\-]+)/?$ site.php?update=true&url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: FYI: QSA stands for "Query String Append"